# Angular 2 & NoSQL: Is it safe to show ID in Route Parameter?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a `business` node in my noSQL database.

[image]

In my angular 2 app, I'm trying to to show data of a busineses with this route configuration: `/business/:name`.

Then I noticed that I can't actually look for a businses by it's name in NoSQL.

**My question is:**

Is it common to show the object ID in URL to show the place data? If yes, is it safe (as long as the rules are ok)?

In this case: `/business/-KUNqai...`

**If not**, is it possible to show it's name and find it someway easily without looping each object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be safe if your rules are ok. Someone could get it anyway from Network logs in DevTools even if you don't show it.

If you want to show names, you could make `friendly_urls` node and store keys there:

```
{ "some-name": "-KUNqai..." }
```

then you can use `/business/some-name`, and lookup it's key there, before loading data.

Comment: we should try to hide data as much as we can. yes you are correct, if the user is smart enough to see the data, he can do that any way in network tab but the non developer users normally do not know how to do that.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Personally I don't believe in hiding stuff, it just gives you sense of false security. You **have to** assume hackers know what to do, and protect your code from them. On the other hand, you **can** assume average user doesn't even look at the address bar (when was the last time you looked at the address bar in your webmail app? :). You have to, at some point, trust your users. And by asking them to sign in you trust them not to abuse your app. So for anything that isn't public (sharable link, for example), you can just use IDs and don't complicate life for yourself...

Comment: agree but some time we need to secure every bit of information like banking application

Comment: I'm not doing friendlfy urls because of "hiding". I use frienldy URL because it improves the product quality, and better to understand where are you at. In my case it's not for SEO, but if you want SEO for your app you better use friendly urls.

Answer (score 0):

Appending user data in the url is always unsafe as everyone can see and its just query paramater.

what ever you are doing you can do it by creating a method in you service and make all your routing through that method. you can do the same thing without exposing data in the url

```
 moveToAnotherPage(value: string, params : any) {
    this.router.navigate([value, params], {skipLocationChange: true});
  }
```

this.router.navigate([value], {skipLocationChange: true});

you see me details in the below link.

[link to code in git](https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/generator-angular2-with-router/blob/master/generators/templates/app/services/app.service.ts#L18:L20)

you can try this generator by

```
npm install -g generator-angular2-with-router
yo angular2-with-router
npm instal
npm start
```

Comment: But then the user can't uses this route directly because there are no params at all?

Comment: you can pass params to the method and add it to your this.route.navigate(). it take params

Comment: added params intake into the method

Comment: Knowing someone's user ID doesn't allow you to impersonate that user. My ID on Stack Overflow is `209103`, that information is publicly available. But unless you know the credentials with which I sign in, it is harmless information. All it does is identify my user record in the Stack Overflow database. There is nothing unsafe about showing a user ID in a URL.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, agree. But facebook or stackoverflow is not equivalent to my internet banking site like wellsfargo.com or FBI  or any secure site where every bit of information is  important. It dependent upen which types of site you are developing.

Comment: Exposing user IDs in URLs is *not* security risk. That applies the same for all types of sites. My Online banking ID is frankvanpuffelen. Knowing that doesn't help you in any way unless you have access to my credentials and my second authentication factor.

Comment: I appreciate you way of thinking but my thinking is different.